# WTForms: IntegerField skips coercion on a string value

Tags: python, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I have a `Form` instance with a single `IntegerField`.

The IntegerField renders to HTML as an `<input>` with `type="text"` and data gets POSTed back from an HTML form as a text string. However the form will not validate if the posted data has a string value for the IntegerField (passed in via a dict in the data parameter).

Here's a toy example:

```py
from wtforms import validators, Form, IntegerField 

class TestForm(Form):
    num = IntegerField('How Many?', [validators.NumberRange(min=1, max=100)])


test_form1 = TestForm()
print("HTML Render 1: %s" % test_form1.num())

data_in = {'num': '66'}  # Note '66' is a string as would be POSTed
test_form2 = TestForm(data=data_in)
print("HTML Render 2: %s" % test_form2.num())
print("     Validate: %s" % test_form2.validate())
print("       Errors: %s" % test_form2.errors)
```

The output is:

```
HTML Render 1: <input id="num" name="num" type="text" value="">
HTML Render 2: <input id="num" name="num" type="text" value="66">
     Validate: False
       Errors: {'num': [u'Number must be between 1 and 100.']}
```

The docstring for IntegerField says:

> IntegerField(Field): A text field, except all input is coerced to an integer

How can I coerce a `str` into an `int` such that this form will pass validation?

Answer (score 3):

[This](https://github.com/wtforms/wtforms/issues/6) is from one of the **WTForms** devs:

> Fields only coerce form data, they don't coerce object data, this lets people use objects >"like an int" and still have them work without the value being clobbered. It's your >responsibility to pass correct datatypes to object/kwargs data.

And from the docs:

> **process_formdata(valuelist)**
>   Process data received over the wire from a form.
>
> This will be called during form construction with data supplied through the formdata 
>   argument.
>
> Parameter: valuelist – A list of strings to process.

In your example the `process_formdata` method on `IntegerField` will never be called

You are passing in a `str` and this will not be coerced because you are supplying it as the `data` keyword argument. The `data` keyword argument signifies exactly the data you want to validate without **coercion**. Because `'66'` is still a `str` the validators won't let it pass.

The `formdata` keyword argument indicates the data coming in off the wire. This will go through the field's **coercion** process. There is only one catch, it only accepts `MultiDict` like objects. If you look at the example below I've used the **webob** `MutliDict` but there is also one supplied in the **Werkzeug** library. If you wrap a regular python dictionary in a `MultiDict` and supply it as the `formdata` keyword your form will validate as expected.

```py
from wtforms import validators, Form, IntegerField 
from webob.multidict import MultiDict

class TestForm(Form):
    num = IntegerField('How Many?', [validators.NumberRange(min=1, max=100)])

data_in = {'num': '66'}  # Note '66' is a string as would be POSTed
test_form2 = TestForm(formdata=MultiDict(data_in))
print("HTML Render 2: %s" % test_form2.num())
print("     Validate: %s" % test_form2.validate())
print("       Errors: %s" % test_form2.errors)
```

---

```
HTML Render 2: <input id="num" name="num" type="text" value="66">
     Validate: True
       Errors: {}
```

Comment: Any idea why this doesn't validate when using '0'? And that's after changing NumberRange to have min=0 and adding validators.DataRequired(). [I posted this question with examples here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25335398/wtforms-integerfield-skips-coercion-when-string-value-is-0)

Comment: ya because `'0'` isn't a number its a `str`! thats what the whole `coercion` business is about. In order to be processed by a `NumberRange` validator it must be coerced into an `int`

Comment: `'0'` is one of those cases where the string causes `NumberRange` to fail cause its not a number also `0` is *Falsey* so it causes the *post-coercion* `if field.data...` check in all `__call__` methods to evaulate *False* as well. For a deeper discussion of this see here(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23982917/flask-wtforms-difference-between-datarequired-and-inputrequired/23984389#23984389)