# Flask WTForms: Difference between DataRequired and InputRequired

Tags: python, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

What is difference between `DataRequired` and `InputRequired` in `wtforms.valiadators`

I have some fields in my signup form :

```
username
password 
password_repeat 
submit
```

Should these fields use the `DataRequired` or `InputRequired` validator?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

### Short Answer

**Unless you have a good reason you should use `InputRequired`**

### Why?

Lets look at some notes from the [docs/code for `DataRequired()`](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/2.3.x/validators/#wtforms.validators.DataRequired) :

> Note there is a distinction between this and DataRequired in that InputRequired looks that form-input data was provided, and DataRequired looks at the post-coercion data.

and

> **NOTE** this validator used to be called `Required` but the way it behaved (requiring coerced data, not input data) meant it functioned in a way which was not symmetric to the `Optional` validator and furthermore caused confusion with certain fields which coerced data to 'falsey' values like `0`, `Decimal(0)`, `time(0)` etc. Unless a very specific reason exists, we recommend using the :class: `InputRequired` instead.

**what does this mean?**

In the `Form` class you will notice two keyword arguments `formdata` and `data`. These generally correspond with two methods `process` and `process_formdata`. When form data comes in off the wire its not always in the format corresponding to the `Field` type. A good example of this is the value `u'1'` being supplied to an `IntegerField`.  This would be bad news if you had a `NumberRange` validator because `u'1'` isn't a number.

The primary purpose of the `process_formdata` method is to prevent this situation by coercing the value into its correct type prior to running validation rules. That is what they are referring to when they say *"looks at the post-coercion data"*

**the problem!**

Both `InputRequired` and `DataRequired` work the same way specifically the `__call__` implementations:

```
def __call__(self, form, field):
    if not field.data or isinstance(field.data, string_types) and not field.data.strip():
        if self.message is None:
            message = field.gettext('This field is required.')
        else:
            message = self.message
```

Certain field types coerce data into *Falsey* values(0, Decimal(0), etc.). The problem occurs when you have an `IntegerField` and the form submits a value like `'0'`. If you apply `DataRequired` to this it will fail validation. This is because `DataRequired` will evaluate `if not field.data...` after coercion where `field.data` is the *Falsey* numeric value `0`.

Comment: thanks for editing my question, and now I do not have enough reputation to vote up. thanks again for the detailed answer

Comment: You can accept the answer if it helped you as an indication to future visitors

Comment: Excellent explanation @nsfyn55. One question though. What is the difference between using `InputRequired()` and `input_required()`?

Comment: @kevin Validators can be factory functions or callable classes. The wtforms docs say the aliasing of input_required to InputRequired "allows you to keep API compatibility as you move your validators from factories to classes, and thus we recommend this for those writing validators they will share."
https://wtforms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/validators.html#custom-validators