# Flask Translate Choice in Form To ForeignKey Pointing to Another Table

Tags: postgresql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

This part of the app works, buts it's ugly and not sustainable. Need a more evolved solution.

PROBLEM I AM TRYING TO SOLVE:

This part of the application enables users to access a form to enter purchases they've made and store them in a Postgres DB. I am using Flask SQLAlchemy ORM.
Within my `purchase` table exists a field `store_id`, that has a ForeignKey relationship to my `store` table. I don't want my user to select a store ID # in the form, so I am using a SelectField to enable them to choose the store name instead. However, I can't seem to find a sustainable way to translate the store name back to its associated ID. Right now I am using the ugly IF statements seen below.

What is a better way to map/translate store name to ID which is already housed in the "store" table in my DB?

MY MODEL:

```
class Purchase(db.Model):
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
item = db.Column(db.String(80))
quantity = db.Column(db.Integer)
unit_cost = db.Column(db.Integer)
total_cost= db.Column(db.Integer)
date = db.Column(db.DateTime)
store_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('store.id'))
```

MY FORM:

```
class CreatePurchase(FlaskForm):

item = StringField('Item', validators=[DataRequired()])
quantity = IntegerField('Quantity', validators=[DataRequired()])
unit_cost = IntegerField('Unit Cost', validators=[DataRequired()])
total_cost = IntegerField('Total Cost', validators=[DataRequired()])
store_id = SelectField("Store Selector", choices=[('0','Select Store'),('1','Furgesons'), ('2','Ocean State'), ('3','Chewy'), ('4','Amazon'),  ('5', 'Rumford')])
date = DateField('Purchase Date', validators=[DataRequired()])
submit = SubmitField('Enter')
```

MY ROUTE:

```
@main.route('/enter_purchases', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def enter_purchase():

form = CreatePurchase()

x = str(form.store_id) # this is a store name from our form
p = 0
if "Ocean State" in x:
    p = 2
elif "Amazon" in x:
    p = 4
elif "Furgesons" in x:
    p = 1
elif "Chewy" in x:
    p = 3
elif "Rumford" in x:
    p = 5


if form.validate_on_submit():
    purchase = Purchase(item=form.item.data, quantity=form.quantity.data, unit_cost=form.unit_cost.data,
                total_cost=form.total_cost.data, date=form.date.data,store_id=p)

    db.session.add(purchase)
    db.session.commit()
    flash('New purchase added successfully')
    return redirect(url_for('main.success'))
return render_template('enter_purchases.html', form=form)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a `store` table, with a numeric id (as the PK) and a name attribute:

```
class Store(db.Model):
     store_id = ..
     store_name = ..
```

You populate your form with all of the **unique** values from the `store_name`. This needs to be a dynamically generated form, so instead of using a form that is statically created do something like:

```
def CreatePurchase()
    class TempForm(FlaskForm):
        item = StringField('Item', validators=[DataRequired()])
        quantity = IntegerField('Quantity', validators=[DataRequired()])
        unit_cost = IntegerField('Unit Cost', validators=[DataRequired()])
        total_cost = IntegerField('Total Cost', validators=[DataRequired()])
        date = DateField('Purchase Date', validators=[DataRequired()])
        submit = SubmitField('Enter')
    choices = ## some SQLalchemy code to get all unique store_names from the table
    TempForm.store_id = SelectField("Store Selector", choices=choices)
    return TempForm()
```

Then `form.store_id` will provide the right id, but display the string name of the store in the form.

The key in this setup is making sure you use the right SQLalchemy code to populate the SelectField dynamically. Basically for each store in the table you can just iterate through something like this:

```
choices = list()
for store in Store.query.all():  # <- assumes store_id and store_names are unique
    choices.append((store.store_id, store.store_name))
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. It seems to work fine as it pulls in the names of the stores and I get no errors The problem I have now when I implement this is that for some reason I get a WTForms error "Not a valid choice".  I am thinking it must have something to do with how I am implementing my view.     if form.validate_on_submit():
        purchase = Purchase(item=form.item.data, quantity=form.quantity.data, unit_cost=form.unit_cost.data,
                    total_cost=form.total_cost.data, date=form.date.data,store_id=form.store_id)

Comment: I have also tried store_id=form.store_id.data and store_id=form.store_id.choices and form.store_id.choices[0]... but I get the same error.  I know the table wants to see the number. Not sure what I am doing wrong

Comment: have you attached the InputRequired() to the SelectField()? (note: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23982917) It *may* also be that the tuple might need to be string data? e.g. `choices.append((str(store.store_id), store.store_name))`

Comment: Thank you Attack68... I needed both the InputRequired and type conversion. Works like a charm now. I appreciate your help!