# Flask form is not validating form on submit

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

In my flask app, on the registration page, the registration form does not validate the data from the form nor adds the data from the form to my database. Please what could be wrong?
Below are my codes. I have check online and couldn't find a solution. And i don't get any errors.

This the
**routes.py**

```
from jokin import app
from jokin import db
from flask import Flask, render_template, flash, url_for
from werkzeug.utils import redirect
from jokin import bcrypt, db
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField, BooleanField, SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, Email, EqualTo, Length, ValidationError

# User Model
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
    email = db.Column(db.String(20), unique=True, nullable=False)
    dp = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False, default='default.jpg')
    password = db.Column(db.String(20), nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"User('{self.username}', '{self.email}', '{self.dp}')"

# Registeration Form
class RegisterationForm(FlaskForm):
    username = StringField('Username', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=2, max=20)])
    name = StringField('Your name', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=2, max=20)])
    email = StringField('Email', validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
    password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired()])
    confirm_password = PasswordField('Confirm Password', validators=[DataRequired(), EqualTo('password')])
    submit = SubmitField('Sign Up')

    # Validate username
    def validate_username(self, username):
        user = User.query.filter_by(username=username.data).first()
        if user:
            raise ValidationError('Username has already been taken')

    # Validate email
    def validate_email(self, email):
        user = User.query.filter_by(email=email.data).first()
        if user:
            raise ValidationError('Email has already been taken')

@app.route("/register", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    form = RegisterationForm()
    # validate the form
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        hashed_password = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(form.password.data).decode('utf-8')
        user = User(username=form.username.data, email=form.email.data, password=hashed_password)
        # add user to db
        db.session.add(user)
        db.session.commit()
        flash('Account Created Successfully', 'success')
        return redirect(url_for('login'))
    return render_template('register.html', form=form)
```

**register.html**

```
        <form action="{{ url_for('register') }}" method="POST">
            {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
            <fieldset>
                <h3 class="border-bottom">Sign Up</h3>
                
                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form.username.label(class="form-control-label") }}
                    {% if form.username.errors %}
                        {{ form.username(class="form-control is-invalid") }}
                        {% for error in form.username.errors %}
                            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                {{ error }}
                            </div>
                        {% endfor %}
                    {% else %}
                        {{ form.username(class="form-control") }}
                    {% endif %}
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form.email.label(class="form-conttol-label") }}
                    {% if form.email.errors %}
                        {{ form.email(class="form-control is-invalid") }}
                        {% for error in form.email.errors %}
                            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                {{ error }}
                            </div>
                        {% endfor %}
                    {% else %}
                        {{ form.email(class="form-control") }}
                    {% endif %}
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form.password.label(class="form-label") }}
                    {% if form.password.errors %}
                        {{ form.password(class="form-control is-invalid") }}
                        {% for error in form.password.errors %}
                            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                {{ error }}
                            </div>
                        {% endfor %}
                    {% else %}
                        {{ form.password(class="form-control") }}
                    {% endif %}
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    {{ form.confirm_password.label(class="form-label") }}
                    {% if form.confirm_password.errors %}
                        {{ form.confirm_password(class="form-control is-invalid") }}
                        {% for error in form.confirm_password.errors %}
                            <div class="invalid-feedback">
                                {{ error }}
                            </div>
                        {% endfor %}
                    {% else %}
                        {{ form.confirm_password(class="form-control") }}
                    {% endif %}
                </div>
            </fieldset>
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ form.submit(class="btn btn-outline-info") }}
            </div>
        </form>
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre], compress all the code in one file in max 70 lines (but less is better) the same about html part

Comment: @Matiiss even after reading MRE, i still don't understand how to do it

Comment: I actually explained in my comment: one continuous piece of code (basically one file) that is super compressed (like 50 to 70 lines but less is better) and anyone could copy - paste that code and it will reproduce the same exact error you get, basically remove everything that doesn't cause the error and code can run without it, also are you sure the form should validate?

Comment: @Matiiss i hope its better now?

Comment: it is better but why do you think it doesn't validate? did you enter valid data?

Comment: i really don't know. Because it doesn't return any errors. When i click submit button, It just skips the validate_on_submit function and renders the template again. And yes I did enter valid data

Comment: wow, took a while, it is that in your form class you have `name` when in the html form you don't have this field so it can't  possibly validate because data is required (btw I read that it is better to almost always use `InputRequired()`: [read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23982917/flask-wtforms-difference-between-datarequired-and-inputrequired))

Comment: OMG! how did i not see that. Thank you very much @Matiiss. I am really grateful. The code is working now

Comment: good to hear that, in case you are wondering how I found that, I put print statements before `form.validate_on_submit()` that printed out `form.username.data`, `form.name.data`, etc. and then I noticed that one of them always came out blank although I had filled all the fields, that is how I noticed that `form.name.data` doesn't print anything and then I noticed that it is not in html form, just a little debugging detail, maybe is useful sometime in future, anyhow, great that your issue is solved now

Comment: definitely going to be very useful for me. I'm really grateful, thanks