# Number Validation Between Range 0 and 100

Tags: python, wtforms, flask-wtforms

My current WTForms Number validator code is as follows:

```
class ScoreForm(Form):
    score = FloatField(validators=[DataRequired(), NumberRange(0,100)])
    submit = SubmitField()
```

I want the score to be specified between 0 and 100 (inclusive of both and decimals allowed).

There are two problems with the above code:

1. It does not let me enter 0 as the value. Doing so spits out the built-in error message

   `[This field is required.]`
2. If I enter some string into the field, i get the same error message as above, which is not the correct message.

How do I correct these two problems?

Comment: I haven't tried it myself, but read recently [here](http://wtforms.simplecodes.com/docs/0.6.1/fields.html#wtforms.fields.FloatField) that DecimalField is preferable to FloatField in the majority of cases, except for some rare cases where an IEEE is needed. Try this NumberRange validator for DecimalField, maybe that will work for you

Comment: I am working with pyMongo and since it has no native support for Decimal , its posing a lot of unwanted problems, if i use DecimalField. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After lot of weird behavior with `FloatField` and `DecimalField`, I finally used `StringField` and wrote a custom validator for my above use case as follows:

```
class ScoreForm(Form):
    score = StringField(validators=[DataRequired()])
    add_score = SubmitField()

    def __init__(self):
        Form.__init__(self)

    def validate(self):
        if not Form.validate(self):
            return False
        try:
            float(self.score.data)
        except ValueError:
            self.score.errors.append(
                'Score must be a valid number')
            return False
        if 0 > float(self.score.data) > 100:
            self.score.errors.append(
                'Score must be in the range 0-100')
            return False
        return True
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue isn't the NumberRange validator, it's the DataRequired validator. See:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/25335781/1194335

TL;DR: DataRequired evaluates 0 as falsey, you'll need to use the InputRequired validator instead!