# WTForms not validating type

Tags: python, wtforms

I'm trying to use `wtforms` to check if the data in a dictionary is of the desired type. In the example below, I want to ensure that `some_field` in a dictionary is an integer. The documentation leads me to believe that if I use `IntegerField`, the data will be coerced to an integer, `StringField` will coerce to string, etc. However, `foo.validate()` is returning `True` even when the type of `some_field` is not an integer. Is this the expected behavior, and why? If it is the expected behavior, is it possible to use `wtforms` to do type validation as desired?

```
>>> from wtforms import Form, IntegerField, validators

>>> class Foo(Form):
...     some_field = IntegerField(validators=[validators.Required()])

>>> foo = Foo(**{'some_field':'some text input'})

>>> foo.data
{'some_field': 'some text input'}

>>> foo.validate()
True

>>> IntegerField?
Type:            type
String form:     <class 'wtforms.fields.core.IntegerField'>
File:            c:\users\appdata\local\continuum\anaconda\envs\env\lib\site-packages\wtforms\fields\core.py
Init definition: IntegerField(self, label=None, validators=None, **kwargs)
Docstring:
A text field, except all input is coerced to an integer.  Erroneous input
is ignored and will not be accepted as a value.
```

Comment: See this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22585652/wtforms-integerfield-skips-coercion-on-a-string-value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data needs to be passed to the form's `formdata` argument in order to force type coercion. In order to pass data to `formdata`, use a `MultiDict`.

```
In [2]: from wtforms import Form, IntegerField, validators

In [3]: class Foo(Form):
   ...:     some_field = IntegerField(validators=[validators.Required()])

In [4]: from werkzeug.datastructures import MultiDict

In [5]: foo = Foo(formdata=MultiDict({'some_field':'some text input'}))

In [6]: foo.data
Out[6]: {'some_field': None}

In [7]: foo.validate()
Out[7]: False
```

Thanks to Max in the comments for pointing out this link with the answer and more details: [WTForms: IntegerField skips coercion on a string value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22585652/wtforms-integerfield-skips-coercion-on-a-string-value)